# how to share a post from your blog on social media by post id in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have this index.html.erb, which makes my posts menu:

```
<%provide(:title, "Recipes") %>



<div class="search_container">
   <%= form_tag(posts_path, :method => 'get', id: "search-form") do %>
     <%= text_field_tag :search,params[:search], placeholder: "Search Tags" %>
     <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
   <% end %>
</div>
   <div class="tag_container">

     <div class="tag_cloud tag_cloud_positioning_and_color_and_stuff">
       <% tag_cloud Post.tag_counts, %w{s m l} do |tag, css_class| %>
         <%= link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag.id), class: css_class %>
       <% end %>
     </div>
   </div>

<div class="posts_wrapper">
  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <div class="card-group card-group-size">
    <div class="card recipes recipes_posts">
      <%= link_to post do %>
       <img src="<%= url_for(post.image) if post.image.attached?  %> " class="index_images">
      <% end %>
      <div class="card-body card_body_size">
        <h5 class="card-title"><%=link_to post.title, post, class: "post_title"%></h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <% end %>
  <%= will_paginate @posts %>
</div>
```

When i chose a post from the menu the show.html.erb is rendered following the specific post_id. In this format it shares the right Post whit the image attached: (it is modified after benj-p gave me the ideea with <%= posts_path(@post) %>):

```
<head>

  <meta property="og:url"           content="https://secretstrawberry.herokuapp.com/posts/<%= @post.id %>" />
  <meta property="og:type"          content="website" />
  <meta property="og:title"         content="<%= @post.title %>" />
  <meta property="og:image"         content="<%= image_tag @post.image %>" />
</head>




<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script async defer crossorigin="anonymous"
 src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_GB</sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v7.0&appId=2751510331745380&autoLogAppEvents=1">
</script>



<%provide(:title, @post.title) %>

<div class="recipe_container">


  <% if logged_in? && current_user.admin? %>
    <div class="edit_delete_buttons_container">
      <div class="edit_delete_buttons">
        <%= link_to "Edit", edit_post_path(@post), {:class => "img_button btn btn-success button_back"} %>
      </div>
      <div class="edit_delete_buttons">
        <%= link_to "Delete", post_path(@post), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" },
                    class: "img_button btn btn-danger" %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>


<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://secretstrawberry.herokuapp.com/posts/<%= @post.id %>"
data-layout="button_count" data-size="small"><a target="_blank"
href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<%= posts_path(@post) %>&amp;src=sdkpreparse"
class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">Share</a></div>


  <div class="tags tags_in_recipe_show">
    Tags:<%= render @post.tags %>
  </div>
  <div class="signup_h1  post_new_button h1_show">

    <h1 id=""><strong><%= @post.title %></strong></h1>



  </div>



  <div class="image_container">

    <% if @post.image.attached? %>
      <%= image_tag @post.image, class: "image_view" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>



  <div class="recipe_body">


    <div class="margin_top_ingredients">
      <pre class="ingredients">
              <%= @post.content %>
       </pre>
    </div>

    <div>
      <pre class="ingredients">
              <%= @post.method %>
      </pre>
    </div>

    <div>
      <pre class="ingredients">
               <%= @post.description %>
      </pre>
    </div>




  </div>





    <div class="recipe_body comments_container ">

      <p id="comment_count"><%= @post.comments.count %> reviews  <%= link_to "Log In", login_path unless logged_in? %> </p>

      <%= render @post.comments.order("created_at DESC").paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)%>


      <div class="form_container_post">
          <%= render 'comments/form' %>

        <div class="paginate">
          <%= will_paginate @comments %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Now this facebook share button is working, sharing the Post title and the post image.

Thank you.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can dynamically get the url of the post and interpolate it in the Facebook share url.

```
 <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<%= post_url(@post) %>&amp;src=sdkpreparse" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">Share</a>
```

Comment: Thank you benj-p. Is a move in the right direction, but i had to do this: <%= posts_path(@post) %>. and also i had to include the <meta> tags, and now is sharing the right post title but not the image.

Comment: Actually after the modifications i had made to the page, all is working well. thanks benj-p for the advice. In the show.html.erb above is a working facebook share button, that shares the post title and the attached image.

Comment: I wasn't sure what your route was but I'm glad it helped ;)